# SSRS 2008 DateTime format issue

Tags: web-services, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, datetime-format

I have a web page accessing the SSRS web service and I have some sample reports created.

These reports have some datetime parameters with Available Values specified i.e. 17/07/2009

Report Manager runs the reports perfectly.

When I access the report in my web page and retrieve the parameters the available values for the datetime parameters appear in the format MM/dd/yyy i.e. 07/17/2009

*parameters = rs.GetReportParameters(reportPath, historyID, forRendering, values, credentials);*

If I update the value to the correct format I can pass the parameters to the report and they work as expected but atm I can't figure out where the conversion is taking place.

Admittedly I'm not too sharp on globalization [or should that be globalisation :)] so I may have missed something obvious.

The report language was changed to en and the page culture was changed to Culture="en-GB" in attempts to resolve the issue [in a quick and dirty way] but no luck

Regional Options on my workstation is set to English (Ireland)
All other parameters work as expected.

Any ideas anyone,

Thanks in advance
Liam

Comment: Did you check the language of the SQL Server where the SRSS web service is located? Sounds like the datatype conversion starts there.

Comment: Ahh its set to English (United States). That may be the issue alright. Although Report Manager seems to manage fine I'm only seeing the parameter label in Report Manager while in my code my code I can see both the label and the value.
Thank you - can you add this as an answer and I can vote up and maybe later mark as an answer

Answer (score 0):

you must set language properties on textbox: Language: en-GB, and put regional setings on Web server where deploy report to English

it works for me, i have same problem with report localization.